# SQL query NOT IN from 3 tables with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have tables scructure:

**old_data**

| email | type |

///////////////////////////////

**clients**

| email1 |

//////////////////////////////

**trashes**

| email |

---

I need to find records that are not in table `clients`, but still exists in table `old_data` where it have type = 'Accounts'. So I wrote this code:

```
SELECT `email` FROM `old_data`
WHERE `type` = 'Accounts' AND `email` NOT IN (SELECT `email1` FROM `clients`))
```

Then I need to find in this result records, that are not in table `trashes`. So I wrote this code:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT `email` FROM `old_data` 
WHERE `type` = 'Accounts' AND `email` NOT IN (SELECT `email1` FROM `clients`)) AS t1 
WHERE t1.email NOT IN (SELECT `email` FROM `trashes`)
```

The problem here is, I have multiple records in table `old_data` for 1 email and type 'Accounts'. Same is in table `trashes`, but not in table `clients`.
I need to write query like:

Get all records from `old_data` where is not `clients` email, but if `clients` email1 matches `old_data` email, remove all records with that emails from result. But then if from this result matches email with email from table `trashes`, remove from result only one record with that email.

Please help, I'm lost...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to work it with another parameter.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT `email`, `secretId` FROM `old_data`
WHERE `type` = 'Accounts' AND `email` NOT IN (SELECT `email1` FROM `clients`)) AS t1 
WHERE t1.secretId NOT IN (SELECT `secretId` FROM `trashes` WHERE `type` = 'Accounts')
```

Also works with

```
SELECT od.`email`, od.`secretId`
FROM `old_data` od
WHERE od.`type` = 'Accounts' AND
      od.`email` NOT IN (SELECT `email1` FROM `clients`) AND
      od.`secretId` NOT IN (SELECT `secretId` FROM `trashes` WHERE `type` = 'Accounts');
```

---

Thanks for helping. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not in` by chaining the conditions.

```
SELECT od.`email`
FROM `old_data` od
WHERE od.`type` = 'Accounts' AND
      od.`email` NOT IN (SELECT `email1` FROM `clients`) AND
      od.email NOT IN (SELECT `email` FROM `trashes`);
```

I prefer `not exists` with a subquery because it handles `NULL` values better.

Comment: I can't mark your answer as useful.... But it have value for me in it, so thanks a lot. :)